# Driver needed: Conexant CX11252-11 Modem Win7x64

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, drivers, modem

I have a [Conexant CX11252-11 Modem](http://www.conexant.com/products/entry.jsp?id=122).

I only found driver for XP, is there a workaround for Win 7 x64, or perhaps I should throw away this modem?

Comment: Check out: [What (traditional) modems work with Windows Vista 64-bit or Windows 7 64-bit?](http://superuser.com/questions/4343/what-traditional-modems-work-with-windows-vista-64-bit-or-windows-7-64-bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drivers for this modem are built into the system. Just choose to manually install from the installed drivers, and scroll the list to find CONEXANT and then PCI CX11252-11 Soft Modem. Works perfectly. I tried it just for fun in Windows 10.

Comment: Are you sing this worked in windows 10 too ?

Comment: @Кир Дарк Wow, I should try this!

Answer (score 2):

This is some really old software modem. Conexant doesn't seem to provide 64 bit drivers.

Best would be to buy some new hardware modem (like [Rosewill Rnx-56usb](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003WM3X8O) which usually have way better driver support (or don't even require any additional as they're primarily an USB-serial port interface with attached serial modem).

Comment: Any workaround/trick before I throw it away?

Comment: Find some virtualization software able to pass-through PCI cards and do some fancy routing to get the internet connection back? No, there's no use for it if you're missing drivers apart from eBay (if anybody wants that card at all).

Comment: I just need it to send/receive faxes.

Comment: You will not be able to use a soft modem without a driver. Most parts of the modem logic are built into the driver software. There are no 64 bit drivers, so you will not be able to use it. Setting up a hypervisor to have some other OS running which is able to access your PCI modem probably will be "more expensive" than just buying a supported modem.

Comment: Agree. Just for anyone still using XP - my modem could be found on the left garbage near my house.

Comment: Do not put electronics into regular garbage, it contains both lots of valuable metals and very toxic elements.

Comment: :( too late, it's already there. Besides what did you want me to do with it??

Comment: Don't know where you live, but usually you are able to return them at electronic retailers and/or some communal deposits for free.